# How to decipher complex DATEADD function from MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, dateadd

I have inherited a query from an old MS Access DB and cannot for the life of me figure out what was trying to be done in this date parameter function.  I normally only use SQL and this seems a bit different.  Can any one assist in describing what this logic is doing?

```
use pdx_sap_user 
go

select po_number, 
       po_issue_date 

from   vw_po_header 

where po_issue_date > getDate() And PO_issue_date < DateAdd("d",-1,DateAdd("m",8,DateAdd("d",-(Day(getDate())-1),getDate())))
```

Comment: Your code is SQL Server code, not MS Access code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**: there is no `getDate()` function in **Access**. Probably it should be `Date()` which returns the current date.
Now starting from the inner expression:
`Day(Date())` returns the current day as an integer `1-31`.
So in `DateAdd("d", -(Day(Date())-1), Date())` from the current date are subtracted as many days as needed to return the 1st of the current month.
Then:

```
DateAdd("m", 8, DateAdd("d", -(Day(Date())-1), Date()))
```

adds 8 months to the the 1st of the current month returning the 1st of the month of the date after 8 months.
Finally:

```
DateAdd("d", -1,...)
```

subtracts 1 day from the date returned by the previous expression, returning the last day of the previous month of that date.
So if you run today `13-Sep-2019` this code, the result will be:

```
30-Apr-2020
```

because this is **the last day of the previous month after 8 months**.

Answer (score 2):

You can de-obfuscate it a lot by using *DateSerial*:

```sql
where 
    po_issue_date > getDate() And 
    po_issue_date < DateSerial(Year(getDate()), Month(getDate()) + 8, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the following:

1. Take the current date
2. Substract the current day of month -1 to get the first day of current month
3. Add 8 month to this
4. Substract 1 day to get the last day of the previous month

So it calculates some deadline in approx 8 months.

But I wonder how a PO issue date can be in the future...